# Function of calling a dialog box, when displaying a list in a dialog box, all text is underlined with two yellow bars. How to remove them?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Future<void> _showDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: codeCountryList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _indexFlag.value = index;
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            codeCountryList[index].image,
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Text(codeCountryList[index].country,
                              style: StyleTextUtils.textCode),
                          const SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Text(codeCountryList[index].prefix,
                              style: StyleTextUtils.textCode),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wrap it in a `Material()`:

```
return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
                 child: Center(....
```